# How to prevent a "replay" with Javascript SDK authResponse

Tags: security, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Javascript SDK to make a web page that is entirely static HTML and Javascript (i.e., it's not dynamically produced web markup via some web app). This web page occasionally uses Javascript to POST data to a server--data which should be tied to a particular Facebook user. I use `FB.getLoginStatus` to determine who the user is. This gives me `authRepsonse` JSON data which looks like this:

```
authResponse:
  accessToken:"AAAC91..."
  expiresIn: 3786
  signedRequest:"Ws93YNGWQeOi..."
  userID: "670..."
```

I can send the `signedRequest` to the server and decode it and validate it there (using my app's secret key), and then I know that the user is, in this case, "670...", so I can presumably safetly perform whatever operation is supposed to happen on the server. Here's the data I extract from the signed request:

```
{"algorithm"=>"HMAC-SHA256",
 "code"=>
  "2.AQAKT...|5hVFYWcu5a...",
 "issued_at"=>1323403518,
 "user_id"=>"670..."}
```

My question is, what prevents an adversary (who somehow got ahold of the encoded authResponse above) from just "replaying" the signedRequest data to my server at a much later time?

The "issued_at" param at first looked promising, but I don't have anything to compare that issued_at time to to see if I should accept this signedRequest or not. The "expiresIn" is another time related parameter, but it's not signed, so I can't trust it. Maybe "code" provides me with extra info, but I don't see how to decode that.

I expect I'm just thinking about this wrong, or using the API in a way I'm not supposed to. Any insights? Thanks.

Comment: curious - what did you use to decode the signedRequest?

Comment: nevermind. finally found the signedRequest documentation with Bing; i don't know why facebook organizes their stuff so poorly.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Answer (score 2):

First of all using an Message Authentication Code (MAC) is a fundamentally insecure approach to the problem of authentication.  You should be storing this information as a server side state,  so that this is never a threat.   By using a cryptographic hash function as an HMAC you introduce the possibility of someone brute forcing your secret key.  Cryptography should only be used when there is no other solution,  instead you are using it to introduce a weakness.   This is a gross misuse of cryptography.

That being said,  you have an issued_at timestamp.  Just take the current timestamp and subtract.  make sure that value is greater than your session timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which part is fundamentally insecure? I was under the impression that thru Facebook's Social Plugins I can create a system that entirely outsources the user account management to Facebook. (Otherwise what's the point of something like *FB.getLoginStatus*?)  As for issued_at, I can't use that because it comes from the client and so could just be completely fabricated--and it's not part of the signed request so I can't verify it.

Comment: @vegashacker  Using an hmac when its more secure to avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: I guess what I'm having trouble seeing is that FB provides these Javascript operations (like `FB.getLoginStatus`). Is Facebook providing an insecure function? Or am I using it in an insecure way? If the latter, I really don't see it. I'm taking the response (the signed request) from `FB.getLoginStatus` and verifying it on a server. This seems exactly what's intended.

Comment: @vegashacker Yeah,  and ASP pages often use a MAC to keep track of ViewState which I also think is a mistake.  There is disagreement in the security world and its my profession.

Comment: OK, I think I'm _beginning_ to get an understanding of this. Can you provide a link (or just inline explain) how someone could bruteforce my FB app's secret key. Something like `for all possible secret keys, k, check if hash_hmac('sha256', payload, k)==expected_sig`. I guess that's fairly straightforward--it's just a matter of how long it takes to perform sha256 on a ton of guesses. thanks.

Comment: @vegashacker also keep in mind that GPU's and FPGA's can perform sha256 calculations extremely fast.